# Homepage taking a different template in Magento

Tags: php, content-management-system, magento, e-commerce

My magento installation at http://parisera.com shows the homepage with different template (Modern) while the inner pages use the template that I need (default).

Where is the control to change the homepage template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the administration, click CMS->pages, there you'll find Homepage as one of the options. You can modify the layout by clicking its design tab.